# Spring Integration With Kafka ErrorHandling

Tags: spring-integration

Iam doing errorhandling for Spring integration with Kafka and using Xml configurations with **spring integration-kafka-2.1.xsd** to go with sync option from outbound channel adaptor. However scema location still showing 1.0 rather than showing 2.1 associated xsd. Hence getting the following error though `spring-integration-kafka-2.1.jar` placed over classpath:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 35 in XML document from file
>   [...\config\outboundKafka_SpringContext.xml] is invalid; nested
>   exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35;
>   columnNumber: 43; **cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is
>   strict, but no declaration can be found for element
>   'int-kafka:request-handler-advice-chain'.**

Can u please do suggest reg this..

Answer (score 0):

Or you use explicit `1.0` version for XSD in your XML config, or you have to switch on Spring Nature in your Eclipse. The main point to refer to XSD in the classpath, not in the internet if that.